# Can I remove the purchase for a non-consumable item from the sandbox AppStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to remove purchases of non-consumable products in the AppStore  using the sandbox?  The response to 'restoreCompletedTransactions" is different after the purchase for the first non-consumable product happens.  For testing purposes, it would be quite valuable to remove these purchases, and see how the different functions return different values after the purchases happened.  Or.. is my only choice to add more and more non-consumable items for testing, and even then, the behavior of 'restoreCompletedTransactions' won't be perfect?

Comment: I haven't used the IAP but I think you can //edit// them...

Comment: You can edit and event delete products when managing your application on apple's developer website.  My question is not about the product, but the actual purchase itself.   Thanks for your reply nevertheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have researched and googled a lot on this, but couldn't find the way to reset. But I read a post where the guy said that for non-consumable inApps the itunesConnect frequently reset/clear the purchase for test accounts, But I have not yet experienced it.

So I think the only way left and what I opted (and what you have suggested too) is to make new non-consumable inApps and be careful about product identifier.

For Example when I was testing I made a non-consumable inApps with identifier:

```
com.[CompanyName].[AppName].inapp.removeAds1
com.[CompanyName].[AppName].inapp.removeAds2
com.[CompanyName].[AppName].inapp.removeAds3
```

and so on

and finally when all was set. I deleted previous ones and made one:

```
com.[CompanyName].[AppName].inapp.removeAds
```

Just a caution: If you delete these inApps (used for testing), you can not use the same identifier (the one you deleted) to create a new one. Not sure if it will be of any help but I am very obsessed regarding the naming conventions :P

Comment: Thanks for the response.   It is somewhat limiting, but the way you describe it is the only way I found to work it too.